# Amazon RDS - Connect from DNS record

Tags: dns, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I've been working on my new server configuration for my website and now I'm a little stuck...

How I can access my RDS instance (MySQL) without using the very long AWS DNS address?

Like I would be able to access my RDS instance from: `db.exemple.com` using a A, CNAME or any other DNS record.

Here's the new configuration:

- Amazon EC2 - Linux Instance - Ubuntu 12.04 w/ LAMP

  - for web services like PHP, Apache, Zend, etc.
- Amazon RDS - MySQL Instance

  - for MySQL database
  - separated from EC2 instance for performance and managing purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a CNAME record that would map to the RDS address. However, it would be rather pointless. All you will get is an extra DNS lookup.

Comment: Yeah but `db.exemple.com` is easier to remember than the Amazon given address! Also, does it slow down the connection when there's an extra DNS lookup?

Comment: Generally once you set it in your application, you are probably not changing it. Yes it will slow down the initial connection, and it will cache until the ttl runs out.

Comment: I'm gonna try it and see if it's very slow compared to the AWS address.

Comment: Amazon actually has documentation for doing this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-rds-db.html